# Populating checkboxes in laravel blade

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

I'm trying to make a form partial that can be reused for both INSERT and UPDATE. I'm stuck on populating checkboxes. Here what I have:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="Paid" value="1" name="Paid" 
{{ (old('Paid') ?? $invoice->Paid ?? false) ? 'checked' : '' }} />
```

It works for when loading the form the first time on both new records and updating. The problem is when a user unchecks the box when editing a record but something else on the form fails validation. When the form loads after failed validation the box that was unchecked is checked again. The database value from $invoice->Paid is loaded because the old() returns false.

Comment: When you use **checkboxes** for both **creating and updating**, there is **no assurance** if the data being returned is from **old input or the database value**. To make this work, you can simply apply an onclick event via JS and change the value of a hidden field everytime someone checks/unchecks (onchange event) it. You can later validate the existence of old upon the value of that hidden field :) Completely my opinion.. If anyone knows better... Go ahead... answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried for hours to get this working. In the end I gave up and installed LaravelCollective HTML package:

https://laravelcollective.com/docs/5.3/html

Form model binding in this package works for populating checkboxes in the above scenario.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to do this like so:

```
{{ old('Paid', $invoice->Paid) ? 'checked="checked"' : '' }}
```

As long as the old value was true, or the `Paid` property of the `$invoice` model is not null/false, then it will apply the checked value, else it will not.

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to test the value of `old('_token')`:

```
@if (!(old('_token') && $invoice->Paid) || (old('Paid')))
checked
@endif
```